# I need to develop a graphical user interface using QT. Here I need to link a c program to the qt designer/creator

Tags: c++, qt

I need to develop a graphical user interface using QT. Here I need to link a c program to the qt designer/creator. I have to call specific functions of the c program when certain buttons on the user interface are clicked and execute those functions, with their output displayed on the user interface..How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: Qt is a C++ framework, not a C framework.

Comment: But languages are object-level compatible.

Comment: But you can't use Qt from C code, not directly anyway, you need to design a wrapper API.

Comment: But you can call a C function directly from Qt slot, provided proper extern declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid question, why downvotes?

First, as comment suggests, you might really want to implement your function in C++, as Qt provides C++ interface. General way to do it is to declare your function as slot and attach to 'click' signal of the button. Then you can emit the output as another signal and attach it to a 'text' slot in textarea widget. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html.

Next, if you really want to call implementation in C, provide a header file with prototypes of those functions with prepended

```
extern "C"
```

linkage specifications. Then you can include this header file from C++ and safely call C functions.